# Query(IMPORTRANGE) throws "Formula Parse Error"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm working with Google Spreadsheets and I've run into a wall with a `query(IMPORTRANGE)` function:

```
=Query((IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet Name!A2:P1000"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16 WHERE Col6 contains 'Abstract & TO'",16))
```

I keep getting a "Formula Parse Error".

Any suggestions on how to resolve the problem?

Comment: The range `Sheet Name!A2:P1000` hints that you are already bypassing the header row by starting in row 2. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you using an actual URL (http://... ) as the first parameter of IMPORTRANGE ?  Are using the formula as was posted in the question?

Comment: I guess your spreadsheets are not connected for importrange: see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want 1 instead of 16 as the last parameter of the query; this parameter means the number of *header rows*, not of headers.

You also have an extra pair of parentheses in your formula. Otherwise the formula is correct (tested in my spreadsheet), although you could shorten it by replacing `select Col1,Col2,..., Col16` with `select *`

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet Name!A2:P1000"),"SELECT * WHERE Col6 CONTAINS 'Abstract & TO'",1)
```

A possible source of your errors is that your spreadsheets are not connected for the purpose of [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en):

> In the new version of Google Sheets, spreadsheets must be explicitly granted permission to pull data from other spreadsheets using `IMPORTRANGE`. The first time the destination sheet pulls data from a new source sheet, the user will be prompted to grant permission.

Unfortunately, you will not see this prompt if your `IMPORTRANGE` command is within a `QUERY`; the parse error is thrown instead as there is nothing for `QUERY` to parse. To connect the spreadsheet, import something first, e.g.,

```
 =IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet Name!A1")
```

You will see `#REF` error; hovering over it shows an explanation and "connect" button.